# Regarding query to find the records after a join on a particular condition

Tags: oracle

I have two table like as shown below, first one is employee having columns

```
empid empname empstaus
```

and second is table is bbb

```
eempid empdept empworty
```

both the table are joined in  id basis

now I have to do a sort of filetering as in emp table staus can be a value or null so for a 
employee whose value is null I need to check in other table bbb and print all the details only for emplyees whose staus is null in emp table please advise how to achieve this , i am using oracle as a database

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly try

```
SELECT b.* 
  FROM bbb b JOIN employee e
    ON b.eempid = e.empid
 WHERE e.empstatus IS NULL
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/296d6/1)** demo.

Comment: @TuntunDfdd Do you need more help with your question?